# Implementing Blades in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 'blades' experience and my CSS isn't quite right...and I don't see why.

- Adding a new blade should simply push everything to the right

**GOAL:**

[image]

**PROBLEM:**
I have given the Widgets a clear on both...and neither the Dashboard Container, nor the Blade Container have a fixed width...so I am confused.

[image]

**STYLE:**

```
/** DASHBOARD CONTAINER **/
.dashboard-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; }
.dashboard-container .widget { clear: both; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }

/** FORM CONTAINER **/
.form-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; height: 500px; padding: 5px; width: 500px; }

/** BLADE CONTAINER **/
.blade-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; padding: 5px; }
.blade-container .blade { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block; height: 500px; padding: 2px; width: 200px; }
```

**CURRENT HTML:**

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="form-container">
            My Very Tall Form
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
            <div class="blade">
                Blade
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does a second blade look inside your HTML ? Is it added right next to the other blade or is it a new blade-container or even a new widget ?

Comment: What do you expect after the screen ends? Scroll? Resize? Neither?

Comment: I expect to have to "Scroll X"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that they need to go somewhere after the screen ends, the default behaviour is to break line, you can avoid that with `white-space: nowrap;`, added `overflow-x: scroll;` so you can scroll through your elements.

Note: I added those properties to `.dashboard-container`

```css
/** DASHBOARD CONTAINER **/
.dashboard-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space:nowrap; }
.dashboard-container .widget { clear: both; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }

/** FORM CONTAINER **/
.form-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; height: 500px; padding: 5px; width: 500px; }

/** BLADE CONTAINER **/
.blade-container { border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; padding: 5px; }
.blade-container .blade { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block; height: 500px; padding: 2px; width: 200px; }
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-container">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="form-container">
            My Very Tall Form
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
            <div class="blade">
                Blade
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
            <div class="blade">
                Blade
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
            <div class="blade">
                Blade
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
            <div class="blade">
                Blade
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so I dont need the SCROLL bar?

Comment: If you need them to resize i would suggest following dippas answer with flexbox.

Comment: Yours ended up being closer to what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

use `flexbox` simplifying your html markup a lot.

```css
.dashboard-container {
  border: solid 1px #FCC4BF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
    height: 500px;
}


/** FORM CONTAINER **/

.form-container {
  border: solid 1px #FCC4BF;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 500px;
}


/** BLADE CONTAINER **/

.blade {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  flex: 0 200px;
  margin: 0 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <div class="form-container">
    My Very Tall Form
  </div>
  <div class="blade">
    Blade
  </div>
  <div class="blade">
    Blade
  </div>
  <div class="blade">
    Blade
  </div>
  <div class="blade">
    Blade
  </div>
  <div class="blade">
    Blade
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with Flexbox Container:

```
.blade-container { display: flex; border: solid 1px #FCC4BF; padding: 5px; }
```

- See this tutorial: http://coursesweb.net/css/css3-flexbox-container